# change bootstrap button text and icon on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a bootstrap3 login/out button in a navbar. I would like to toggle the text and icon when the button is clicked.

Here is the navbar code:

```
<li><a id="login" class="showLogin" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
```

I found the code below, and it works perfectly:

```
$('#login').on('click', function () {

    var $el = $(this)

    textNode = this.lastChild;
    $el.find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-log-out glyphicon-log-in');
    textNode.nodeValue = ($el.hasClass('showLogin') ? ' Logout' : ' Login')
    $el.toggleClass('showLogin');
});
```

I put this code into a function, but I am getting an error:

"Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined"

Here is the code:

```
function change_login_button(){
    var $el = $('#login')

    textNode = $el.lastChild
    $el.find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-log-out glyphicon-log-in');
    textNode.nodeValue = ($el.hasClass('showLogin') ? ' Logout' : ' Login')
    $el.toggleClass('showLogin'); 
}
```

The problem seems to be the difference between doing this:

```
var $el = $(this)
```

and this:

```
var $el = $('#login')
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, or if there is a simpler way to toggle a bootstrap navbar button?

Comment: your variable "textNode" is not defined as a variable in the first place:
     var textNode = $el.lastChild;

Comment: I'm not seeing how that would make a difference.

Comment: because you are using a variable without defining it as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Login text inside a span and then use the jquery :last-child selector as :

```
var $el2 = $('#login span:last-child');
```

Check this fiddle here : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jairajdesai/x55npa90/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#login').on('click', function() {
    change_login_button();
  });
});

function change_login_button() {
  var $el = $('#login');
  var $el2 = $('#login span:last-child');
  textNode = $("#login span:last-child").text();
  $el.find('span.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-log-out glyphicon-log-in');
  textNode = ($el.hasClass('showLogin') ? 'Logout' : 'Login');
  $el2.text(textNode);
  $el.toggleClass('showLogin');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
  <li>
    <a id="login" class="showLogin" href="#">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> 
</span>  <span>Login</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```